# Pandas - Rolling slope calculation

Tags: python, pandas, regression

How to calculate slope of each columns' rolling(window=60) value, stepped by 5?

I'd like to calculate every 5 minutes' value, and I don't need every record's results.

Here's sample dataframe and results:

```
df
Time                A    ...      N
2016-01-01 00:00  1.2    ...    4.2
2016-01-01 00:01  1.2    ...    4.0
2016-01-01 00:02  1.2    ...    4.5
2016-01-01 00:03  1.5    ...    4.2
2016-01-01 00:04  1.1    ...    4.6
2016-01-01 00:05  1.6    ...    4.1
2016-01-01 00:06  1.7    ...    4.3
2016-01-01 00:07  1.8    ...    4.5
2016-01-01 00:08  1.1    ...    4.1
2016-01-01 00:09  1.5    ...    4.1
2016-01-01 00:10  1.6    ...    4.1
....

result
Time                A    ...      N
2016-01-01 00:04  xxx    ...    xxx
2016-01-01 00:09  xxx    ...    xxx
2016-01-01 00:14  xxx    ...    xxx
...
```

Can df.rolling function be applied to this problem?

It's fine if NaN is in the window, meaning subset could be less than 60.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that what you want is rolling with **a specific step size**. 
However, according to the [documentation of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), step size is currently **not supported** in `rolling`.

If the data size is not too large, just perform rolling on all data and select the results using indexing.

Here's a sample dataset. For simplicity, the time column is represented using integers.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(500, 1) * 10, columns=['a'])
```

```
            a
0    8.714074
1    0.985467
2    9.101299
3    4.598044
4    4.193559
..        ...
495  9.736984
496  2.447377
497  5.209420
498  2.698441
499  3.438271
```

Then, roll and calculate slopes,

```py
def calc_slope(x):
    slope = np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 1)[0]
    return slope

# set min_periods=2 to allow subsets less than 60.
# use [4::5] to select the results you need.
result = data.rolling(60, min_periods=2).apply(calc_slope)[4::5]
```

The result will be,

```
            a
4   -0.542845
9    0.084953
14   0.155297
19  -0.048813
24  -0.011947
..        ...
479 -0.004792
484 -0.003714
489  0.022448
494  0.037301
499  0.027189
```

Or, you can refer to this post. The first answer provides a numpy way to achieve this:
[step size in pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301042/is-there-no-option-for-step-size-in-pandas-dataframe-rolling-is-there-another-f)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
windows = df.groupby("Time")["A"].rolling(60)
df[out] = windows.apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(range(60), x, 1)[0], raw=True).values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas Resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). Note that to use this , you need an index with time value

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
print df
result = df.resample('5Min').bfill()
print result
                                 Time    A    N
Time                                           
2016-01-01 00:00:00  2016-01-01 00:00  1.2  4.2
2016-01-01 00:01:00  2016-01-01 00:01  1.2  4.0
2016-01-01 00:02:00  2016-01-01 00:02  1.2  4.5
2016-01-01 00:03:00  2016-01-01 00:03  1.5  4.2
2016-01-01 00:04:00  2016-01-01 00:04  1.1  4.6
2016-01-01 00:05:00  2016-01-01 00:05  1.6  4.1
2016-01-01 00:06:00  2016-01-01 00:06  1.7  4.3
2016-01-01 00:07:00  2016-01-01 00:07  1.8  4.5
2016-01-01 00:08:00  2016-01-01 00:08  1.1  4.1
2016-01-01 00:09:00  2016-01-01 00:09  1.5  4.1
2016-01-01 00:10:00  2016-01-01 00:10  1.6  4.1
2016-01-01 00:15:00  2016-01-01 00:15  1.6  4.1
                                 Time    A    N
```

Output

```
Time                                           
2016-01-01 00:00:00  2016-01-01 00:00  1.2  4.2
2016-01-01 00:05:00  2016-01-01 00:05  1.6  4.1
2016-01-01 00:10:00  2016-01-01 00:10  1.6  4.1
2016-01-01 00:15:00  2016-01-01 00:15  1.6  4.1
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want for output is the slope value of last five records.
Time stamp starts with 00:00, so 00:04 is the first row of the output.
(1-> 00:00, 2-> 00:01, 3-> 00:02, 4-> 00:03, 5-> 00:04)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
    df['slope_I'] = df['I'].rolling('600s').apply(lambda x: (x[-1]-x[0])/600)
```

where the slope is something with 1/seconds units.

Probably the first 600s of the result will be empty, you should fill it with zeros, or with the mean.
The first number in the slope column will be the slope of the line that goes from the first row inside the window to the last, and so on during the rolling.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

For other answer seekers, here I got another solution where the time interval does not need to be the same length.

```
df.A.diff(60)/df.Time.diff(60).dt.total_seconds()
```

This line of code takes the difference of the current row with sixty rows back and divide this by the difference in time of the same rows.
When you only want every fifth record then the next line should work.

```
df.A.diff(60)/df.Time.diff(60).dt.total_seconds()[4::5]
```

Note: every line is calculated and only the 5 stepped serie is returned

doc pandas diff: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html